# Is it possible to ensure two generic types implement generic interfaces of the same inner type?

Tags: c#, generics

This is a functional example of what I want to achieve:

```
public void Create <TFrame, TOptions, TBuilder> (Action<TBuilder> configurer)
    where TFrame : IConfigurable<TOptions>
    where TBuilder : IOptionsBuilder<TOptions>
{
            
}
```

My question is essentially: is it possible to omit the `TOptions` from this method? I don't care what `TOptions` is, as long as `TFrame` has `T Options {set;}` and `TBuilder` has `T Options {get;}`.

Comment: No, generic constraints cannot use open generic types, and making `IConfigurable<T>` covariant isn't possible because `T` is used in an input position.

Comment: The other possibility is to have `IConfigurable<T>` extend a non-generic interface and constrain to that.

Comment: One option is to make a generic class `class CreateFactory<TFrame, TOptions>     where TFrame : IConfigurable<TOptions> { public void Create<TBuilder> (Action<TBuilder> configurer) where TBuilder : IOptionsBuilder<TOptions> {` Then you can call it like this `CreateFactory<SomeFrameClass, SomeOptions>.Create(yourActionHere)` and you don't need to declare `TBuilder`.